# How to play itunes videos in iphone?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I am new to iPhone development. I have a URL of a site.

On clicking the "visit itunes" button on page, the itunes for that particular site is opened in my Mac iTunes.

I am able to see the videos in iTunes. How can I implement this in my iPhone so that i can see the video in my iPhone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need [Media Player Framework](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/index.html). If you use [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html) you can use `initWithContentURL` to show video from a URL.

Comment: That url invokes the mac itunes.So initWithContentURL will work for that url?